# regex multiple strings in one string

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file that I iterate over and want to check for multiple substrings in each line (1 substring will exist per line).

my regex is the following

`String rE = "(AGG|TIP|IDV|DVY|IYR|LQD|HYG|EMB|ACWI|ACWX|EFA|SCZ|EEM|IWB|IWF|IWD|IWM|IWO|IWN|IWV|IVV|IVW|IVE|IJH|IJK|IJJ|MUB|IJR|IJS|IJT|SPY)"`

and a line of my text file looks like this:

`SPY,6696832,31080,140.7,400,140.69,140.69,6396960,299872`

yet when i do:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
System.out.println("Starting");
while ((retStr = in.readLine()) != null) {
    if(retStr.matches(tickers)){
         System.out.println(retStr);
    }
}
```

I do not find my strings.

The code compiles and runs perfectly. I iterate over the file, yet I never find my result.

Could I please have some help on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `matches(...)` must match the whole String. Consider showing more file lines so we can see other configurations of your text lines that you must analyze.

Comment: it says in the documentation that it takes a regex as an argument: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)

Comment: jason: I don't see any posts or comments that disagree with that statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `.*` to the end of your regex (`.*` matches anything):

```
String rE = "(AGG|TIP|IDV|DVY|IYR|LQD|HYG|EMB|ACWI|ACWX|EFA|SCZ|EEM|" +
     "IWB|IWF|IWD|IWM|IWO|IWN|IWV|IVV|IVW|IVE|IJH|IJK|IJJ|MUB|IJR|IJS|IJT|SPY).*"
```

Comment: so close and yet so far! thanks so much. will accept when i can!!

Comment: @jasonm: he guessed correctly that all your lines of text began with the String your seek. Next time please don't make us guess and show more lines of the text file.

Comment: regardless its obvious.. "\*.(FOO|BAR).\*"

Comment: @jasonm, Did he guess correctly?  Does the match always occur at the beginning of the line?  If so, you should *not* add `.*` to the front of the regex.  (I'm assuming that's what you meant to say in your comment; `*.(FOO|BAR).*` won't even compile.)

Answer (score 1):

For better performance you should compile the regular expression. The `matches` method on String recompiles the expression each time, it is not meant to be used inside a loop.

Here's an example

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Example {

    @Test
    public void shouldMatchString() {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(AAA|BBB|CCC)");
        assertEquals(true, p.matcher("AAA,1,2,3,4,5").find());
        assertEquals(false, p.matcher("    AAA").find());
    }

}
```

Find does not match against the whole string, so I'm using `^` to match the begin of the input.